# Relations to unlimited unknown future tables

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm working on my own genealogy software where I want to be able to add unlimited amount of sources, notes and places to a event. But I have a problem regarding the source tables.
It's not possible to create one table that fits all types of source.

Example of sources

Source: Letter

- To
- From
- Date
- Text

Source: Internet

- Website
- Date
- Text

Source: Census

- Year
- State
- County
- Adress... and so on.

So my solution so far is to create a special table for each source type and link them to a event_vs_source table

```
ID             INT
eventID        VARCHAR
sourceID       INT
sourceTable    VARCHAR
```

Data will then be:

```
ID          453
eventID     67
sourceID    345
sourceTable source_letter
```

source_letter

```
ID        INT
To        VARCHAR
From      VARCHAR
Date      DATE
Text      BLOB
```

But the problem is when I want to fetch all sources connected to a single event.

```
SELECT * FROM event_vs_source WHERE event_vs_source.eventID = 67;
```

this is giving me an array with the name of the source table, source_letter, but how do I use it in a JOIN to select the correct table and find the source ID in it?
I can do it if I do separate queries but what if I have multiple sources connected to one event and all of them are on different source tables?

event_vs_source

```
ID          486
eventID     67
sourceID    23
sourceTable source_website
```

That will result in even more separate queries.

Or am I designing this database wrong?
Is there a better way to do it?

Bottom line is that I want to be able to add as many sources, places and notes to a single event but also unlimited new and unknown future tables yet have a few database request per person. And remember that a person can hanv unlimited amount of events.....

Comment: What about keeping common information like id, type, and date in one source table, and the type-dependent fields in a source-field table (source id, field id, value)?

Comment: That's the latest of my ideas, doing what you suggest. but the end result would be multiple source_filed tables due to some sources might need more then one date and other needs a place or two. I want to be able to add anything to a source, no limits at all. I have been thinking about creating the sources as text-files on the server instead of doing multiple queries to reduce the number of connections/calls to the db.

Comment: It's really to bad you can't use the contents of a cell in a query as the name of another table. Like SELECT * FROM sources.sourceTable WHERE sources.sourceTable.ID = event.ID